# Discord.js bot not firing events when a message is sent after update

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I used to work on discord bots a while back. However, the message event that I used to handle commands isn't working any more, after an update to discordjs.

I've tried both `client.on('message', () => {})` and `client.on('interactionCreate', () => {})`. However, neither of them seem to fire. Could anybody help?

Comment: In discord.js v13 it is now called `messageCreate` and you need to enable all required `Intents` manually. Did you already do that?

Comment: Posted it as a "real" answer as well for a better overview. And I'm glad I could help you :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In **discord.js v13** it is now called `messageCreate` instead of `message`:

```js
client.on('messageCreate', () => {
   // some code
});
```

Also, you need to enable all required `Intents` **manually**, for example:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
   intents: [
      Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
      Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS
   ]
});
```